# Bold part of string in table python docx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I'm iterating through two columns and would like to add the text of one list to a table cell followed by the other, and I'd like to boldthe contents of the other list.  Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
document = Document()
table = document.add_table(rows=int(np.ceil(len(line_items_sample)/3)), cols=3)
index = 0
for item,quantity in zip(line_items_sample['title'].tolist(), line_items_sample['quantity']):
    print(item)
    if index % 3 == 0:
        row = table.add_row().cells
        row[0].text = item.upper() + ' ' + quantity
    if index % 3 == 1:
        row[1].text = item.upper() + ' ' + quantity
        
    else:
        row[2].text = item.upper() + ' ' + quantity
    index = index + 1
```

To be clear, I want item to maintain upper casing and bold quantity. I think what I'm having trouble with is understanding how to have two different styles within one cell in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reread your requirement after I developed my first answer, which didn't take two lists into consideration.

Here is one way to accomplish your use case.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
records_one = ['Dogs', 'Cats', 'Birds']
records_two = ['Bark', 'Meow', 'Chirp']

# add_table() creates your base table 
# you can add additional columns by 
# modifying the variable "cols"
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)

hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells

# you can add columns headers this way
hdr_cells[0].text = 'column one'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'column two'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'column three'

for item_one, item_two in zip(records_one, records_two):
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    
    part_one_cell = row_cells[0]
    part_one_cell.paragraphs[0].add_run(item_one)
    part_one_cell.paragraphs[0].add_run(f' {item_two.upper()}').bold = True
    
    # additional cells can be added these ways
    # 
    # row_cells[1].text = "some sample text"
    # row_cells[2].text = "some more sample text"
    # 
    # or this way
    # 
    # second_cell = row_cells[1]
    # second_cell.paragraphs[0].add_run("some sample text")
    # third_cell = row_cells[2]
    # third_cell.paragraphs[0].add_run("some more sample text")

document.save('demo.docx')
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: this looks good however, I also want it to be a table with 3 cols, how would I modify to get that?

Comment: I updated the answer with the additional columns.  I added some information on how to add more columns, headers and rows.

Comment: this is causing my document to begin with a ton of whitespace.  Anyway to fix that?

Comment: I would have to see you code to see what is happening, because my code produces no extra whitespace.  So please open a new question with the code.